# Language of errors in WordPress admin

Tags: errors, language

How can I change the Wordpress error message language? The language of my WordPress installation is set to Russian. The entire site and the admin panels are in Russian, but the error messages (bad login, etc.) are in English. How can I make sure the error messages are translated as well?

Comment: Is this native wordpress error messages or error message from your theme or a plugin

Comment: I thinks so. Well, I have also installed woocommerce plugin which is also in russian on site and admin panel. For example, bad password error: "ERROR: The password you entered for the username..." - this is native Wordpress error, right?

Comment: Yes it is native wordpress error messages. Have you downloaded wordpress in russian

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Disable "Polylang" plugin solves the problem